# magento UPS Test Error is showing after upgrade 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, ups

After Upgrade Magento 1.7 to 1.9.3 I am getting error on checkout page in UPS Shipping additional Test line is showing i checked in admin but there on Test option How to remove this

```
http://www.screencast.com/t/csyRTo5i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be another shipping method error. Check if you have enabled any other shipping method with title set as "Test" which also not available at this time.
In my case it was "Table Rate" shipping.